# cocos3d: How can I attach shadow to pod object

Tags: ios, cocos3d

How can I enable shadow effect on *.pod object?
I set up camera and light but my object didn't have shadow.
Can somebody explain how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable shadows in cocos3d, you must first set

```
_viewController.viewShouldUseStencilBuffer = NO;
```

to

```
_viewController.viewShouldUseStencilBuffer = YES;
```

in the application delegate.

Next, you must add shadow volumes to the objects of a scene manually.

You can do this by adding this method call to the initialization method of your cc3scene subclass:

```
[self addShadowVolumesForLight:yourLight];
```

in order to add shadow volumes to every object in the scene for a specific light, or:

```
[self addShadowVolumes];
```

to do the same for all lights in the scene.

alternatively you can do the same for specific objects in the scene, if you want to limit shadowing.
e.g.

```
[someObject addShadowVolumesForLight:yourLight];
[someObject addShadowVolumes];
```

Comment: p.s. for some reason shadows don't seem to work with opengles 1 on my system, but they do for opengles 2. Not sure if its a local problem or not.